# How do I format a duration String into a days-hours-minutes String?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, format

I have a String which looks like this:

```
"1.10:05"
```

Now, how do I turn this String into the format of:

[image: formatted string]

Comment: you can use Dart's inbuilt DateTime APIs

Comment: @TirthPatel if the provided string is coming as a response from some other service, then no, they can't use the inbuilt DateTime APIs. They'll need to convert the given string into the result they want/need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dart
  var full = '1.10:35';
  var dayAndRest = full.split('.'); // ['1', '10:35']
  var hrAndMins  = dayAndRest[1].split(':'); // ['10', '35']
  var formatted  = '${dayAndRest[0]}d ${hrAndMins[0]}h ${hrAndMins[1]}min';
  print(formatted); // '1d 10h 35min'
```